# In some browsers it doesn't post after submitting

Tags: php, html

I know that I need to change to MySQLi ! 
The problem here is: in some browsers it doesn't post after submitting, like in Chrome, Opera, Mozilla but it works and it post after submitting from Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge.
At the beginning it worked with no problems in all browsers.
Live website link: [Check out here !](https://www.xeongameshop.com/derank/)
To TEST it you should post only links like this: steam://joinlobby/730/109775244931424928/76561198819667596

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-118227878-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-118227878-1');
</script>

<meta name="description" content="THE BEST CS:GO DERANK LOBBY FINDER SERVICE">
<meta name="keywords" content="CSGO, CS:GO, COUNTER-STRIKE:GLOBAL OFFENSIVE, DERANK, STEAM, LOBBY, FINDER, LOBBIES, DERANK LOBBIES, ROAD TO SILVER, DERANKING, FALLING RANKS">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='https://www.xeongameshop.com/img/newXEONlogo.png' type='image/x-icon' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.styled-select select {
   background: #222222;
   color: white;
   width: 200px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 1px solid;
   border-radius: 3px;
   height: 44px;
   font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;   
   }
</style>
<style> 
input[type=url] {
    padding: 12px 20px;
    background-color: #222222;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
}

input[type=url]:focus {
    background-color: #222222;
}
</style>
<style>
::placeholder {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color: #FFFFFF;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
<style>
.inputFont{
 font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;   
}
</style>

<title>XEON&trade; CS:GO DERANK</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body background="BG005.jpeg">
<script type="text/javascript">
//auto expand textarea
function adjust_textarea(h) {
    h.style.height = "20px";
    h.style.height = (h.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
</script>
<br/>
<br/>
<center>
<img src="XEONLogo.png"/>
</center>


<div align="center">

<form action="index.php" method="post">

<table style="width:10%" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0" >
    <tr>

        <td><input class="inputFont" pattern="steam?://.+" placeholder="steam://joinlobby/730/" type="url" name="lobby" size="58"></td>
        <td><input type="image" src="post.png" alt="Submit Form" value="SUBMIT" name="submit" /></td>

    </tr>
</table>

<table style="width:10%" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0" >
    <tr>

                <td class="styled-select">
        <select required name="Location">
        <option value="U.S.A.">U.S.A.</option>
        <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
        <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
                <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
        </select>
        </td>

        <td class="styled-select">
        <select required name="ranks">
        <option value="Any rank">Any rank</option>
        <option value="Silver ONLY">Silver ONLY</option>
        <option value="Gold Nova and below">Gold Nova and below</option>
        <option value="Master Guardian and below">Master Guardian and below</option>
        <option value="Global and below">Global and below</option>
        </select>
        </td>

        <td class="styled-select">
        <select required name="playstyle">
        <option value="AFK ONLY">AFK ONLY</option>
        <option value="NO AFK">NO AFK</option>
        <option value="AFK and NO AFK">AFK and NO AFK</option>
        <option value="MOLOTOV TACTICS">MOLOTOV TACTICS</option>
        </select>
        </td>

        <td class="styled-select">
        <select required name="rounds">
        <option value="WIN 3 rounds">WIN 3 rounds</option>
        <option value="NO 3 rounds">NO 3 rounds</option>
        </select>
        </td>

        <td class="styled-select">
        <select required name="players">
        <option value="Need 1 player">Need 1 player</option>
        <option value="Need 2 players">Need 2 players</option>
        <option value="Need 3 players">Need 3 players</option>
        <option value="Need 4 players">Need 4 players</option>
        </select>
        </td>



    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<br/>
<div align="center">
<b>
<a href="AFK.rar">
<font style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" color="#E56717">
(Download AFK.CFG)
</font>
</a>
<font face = "Times New Roman" color="white">
 - UNRAR and put the AFK.cfg file into your 
</font>
<font style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" color="white">
( C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg )
</font>
<br/>
<font face = "Times New Roman" color = "white">
To run the config in CS:GO write in the console 
<font style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" color="#E56717">
exec AFK.cfg
</font>
</font>
<br/>
<font face = "Times New Roman" color="white">
To turn
</font>
<font style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" color="#E56717">
(ON / OFF)
</font> 
<font face = "Times New Roman" color="white">
the AFK MODE just type in the console
<font style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" color="#E56717">
(afk)
</font>
</font>
</b>

</div>
<br/>

    <?php

mysql_connect("sql.domain.com", "user05755", "pass");
mysql_select_db("user05755");

$dbLink = mysql_connect("sql.domain.com", "user05755", "pass");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink);
    mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink);

function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'year',
        'm' => 'month',
        'w' => 'week',
        'd' => 'day',
        'h' => 'hour',
        'i' => 'minute',
        's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}

function cleanInput($input) {

  $search = array(
    '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   // Strip out javascript
    '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
    '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
    '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments
  );

  $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
  return $output;
}

function sanitize($input) {
    if (is_array($input)) {
        foreach($input as $var=>$val) {
            $output[$var] = sanitize($val);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $input = stripslashes($input);
        }
        $input  = cleanInput($input);
        $output = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
    }
    return $output;
}

$lobby = sanitize($_POST['lobby']);
$Location = sanitize($_POST['Location']);
$ranks = sanitize($_POST['ranks']);
$playstyle = sanitize($_POST['playstyle']);
$rounds = sanitize($_POST['rounds']);
$players = sanitize($_POST['players']);

$submit = sanitize($_POST['submit']);

if($submit) {
$timestamp = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
    if(
        $lobby &&
        $Location &&
        $ranks &&
        $playstyle &&
        $rounds &&
        $players &&
        $timestamp
    ) {
        $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO derank (lobby,Location,ranks,playstyle,rounds,players,timestamp) VALUES ('$lobby','$Location','$ranks','$playstyle','$rounds','$players','$timestamp') ");
        echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='0; url=index.php'>";
    }

}
?>

<?php

$dbLink = mysql_connect("sql.domain.com", "user05755", "pass");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
    mb_language('uni');
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    $getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `derank` WHERE id > (SELECT MAX(id) AS mID FROM `derank`)-5 ORDER BY id DESC");
    $counter=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `derank`");
    $num_rows=mysql_num_rows ( $counter);
    if($num_rows > 5){
    $delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM derank ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
}
?>
    <div>
<div align='center' >
<div class='wrap-table100'>
<div class='table100 ver3 m-b-110'>
<div class='table100-head'>
<table>
<thead>
<tr class='row100 head'>

<th class="cell100 column1">Posted</th>
<th class="cell100 column8">Location</th>
<th class="cell100 column2">Ranks</th>
<th class="cell100 column3">Playstyle</th>
<th class="cell100 column4">Rounds</th>
<th class="cell100 column5">Players</th>
<th class="cell100 column6">Join Lobby</th>
<th class="cell100 column7">&nbsp;</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class='table100-body js-pscroll'>
    <table>
    <tbody>
<?php
    // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
    {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo '<tr class="row100 body">';
                                    echo '<td style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="cell100 column1">';
                                    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $row['timestamp']);
                                    echo time_elapsed_string($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                                    echo '</td>';
                                                                        echo '<td style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="cell100 column8">';
                                                                        echo "<span style='width:1em'><img style='margin-right:1em' src='".$row['Location'].".png'/></span>";
                                    echo $row['Location'];
                                    echo '</td>';
                                    echo '<td style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="cell100 column2">';
                                    echo $row['ranks'];
                                    echo '</td>';
                                    echo '<td style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="cell100 column3">';
                                    echo $row['playstyle'];
                                    echo '</td>';
                                    echo '<td style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="cell100 column4">';
                                    echo $row['rounds'];
                                    echo '</td>';
                                    echo '<td style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="cell100 column5">';
                                    echo $row['players'];
                                    echo '</td>';
                                    echo '<td style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="cell100 column6">';
                                    echo '<a href="'.$row[lobby].'">';
                                    echo '<img src="JOIN.png"/>';
                                    echo '</a>';
                                    echo '</td>';
                                    echo '<td class="cell100 column7">&nbsp;</td>';
                                echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo '
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ';

?>


<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.js-pscroll').each(function(){
            var ps = new PerfectScrollbar(this);

            $(window).on('resize', function(){
                ps.update();
            })
        });


    </script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
<center><font style="font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;" color="#FFFFFF">2015-<?php echo date("Y"); ?> XEONGameShop</font><font color = "white">&trade;</font></center>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do some research on PDO and prepared statements. Direct SQL query concatenation is no longer considered safe best practice.

Comment: It's POSTing, but you'll need to do some troubleshooting to find out why. Echo/var_dump/log what your inputs contain, if it's getting to the submit/insert section of your code, etc.